# JWT token expire successfully but still able to access Django API's

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I'm using JWT token auth in django.
I set access-token timing to '1 minute' after 1-min the access & refresh token get expire and but when i try to access API url it gives access and show data.

i check with the verifyToken same token shows invalid.
and using same token for api call it shows success=True and print 'hello1'

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with JWT
Check below code for referance.

JWT Docs for referance.
https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Code:

**Setting.py**

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=1),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer', ),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=1),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}
```

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'slash.controllers.pagination.PageNumberCustomPagination',
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema',
}
```

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('0 23 * * *', 'slash.cron.delete_expired_blacklisted_token'),
]
```

```
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'GET',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
    'PATCH',
    'DELETE',
    'OPTIONS'
)
```

```
DRF_API_LOGGER_DATABASE = True
DRF_LOGGER_QUEUE_MAX_SIZE = 50
DRF_LOGGER_INTERVAL = 10
DRF_API_LOGGER_EXCLUDE_KEYS = ['password', 'token', 'access', 'refresh'] # Sensitive data will be replaced with "***FILTERED***".
DRF_API_LOGGER_SLOW_API_ABOVE = 200
```

**URLS.py**

```
path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
path('token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify'),
path('token/blacklist/', TokenBlacklistView.as_view(), name='token_blacklist'),
path('api/student/', StudentAPI.as_view({'post': 'student'}), name='student'),
```

**Views.py**

```
from requests import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.viewsets import ViewSet
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status


class StudentAPI(ViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def student(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('hello1')
        return Response({"success": True}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

`

I followed the completed docs of JWT django auth but still facing same issue.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: hi, have you found the solution ? I am also facing the same problem.

Comment: @Inam Yes i found solution 'VERIFYING_KEY': None, Remove this from setting.py 
"